# When I join 3 tables in 1 query, I get no results; but when I split them as CTEs I can results?

Tags: t-sql, inner-join, common-table-expression

When I execute the query below, I get no results returned:

```
SELECT 
    S.FirstName, S.LastName, S.StudentId, Y8.SectionId
FROM
    SR_Students AS S 
    INNER JOIN
    SR_Student_Classes AS Y7 ON 
        S.StudentId = Y7.StudentId
        AND S.IsActive = 1 AND S.Gender LIKE 'M%'
        AND Y7.TermId = 21 AND Y7.CampusId = 1 AND Y7.ClassId = 7 AND Y7.IsActive = 1
    INNER JOIN
    SR_Student_Classes AS Y8 ON 
        Y7.StudentId = Y8.StudentId
        AND Y8.TermId = 26 AND Y8.CampusId = 7 AND Y7.ClassId = 8 AND Y8.IsActive = 1
```

However, when I split it up (as follows), I get 59 rows returned:

```
; WITH Y7 AS (
    SELECT S.StudentId, S.FirstName, S.LastName, C.ClassID, C.SectionId, C.TermID, C.CampusId 
    FROM 
        SR_Student_Classes AS C
        INNER JOIN SR_Students AS S ON C.StudentId = S.StudentId
    WHERE 
        C.TermId = 21 AND C.CampusId = 1 AND C.ClassId = 7 AND C.IsActive = 1
        AND S.Gender = 'M' AND S.IsActive = 1
)
, Y8 AS (
    SELECT S.StudentId, S.FirstName, S.LastName, C.ClassID, C.SectionId, C.TermID, C.CampusId 
    FROM 
        SR_Student_Classes AS C
        INNER JOIN SR_Students AS S ON C.StudentId = S.StudentId
    WHERE 
        C.TermId = 26 AND C.CampusId = 7 AND C.ClassId = 8 AND C.IsActive = 1
        AND S.Gender = 'M' AND S.IsActive = 1
)
SELECT 
    Y8.FirstName, Y8.LastName, Y8.StudentId, Y8.SectionId
FROM
    Y7 AS Y7 
    INNER JOIN 
    Y8 AS Y8 ON Y7.StudentId = Y8.StudentId
```

I know the 2nd query is correct because I know the underlying data.

But why is the first query not working? It is, after all, using all inner joins?

I also tried moving most of the inner join conditions of the 1st query into a WHERE clause, it made no difference (given that they are inner joins, I didn't expect any difference)

Comment: Your two CTEs aren't doing the same thing as the original query.  Just inline the CTE code into your final select, and you'll see that the queries are substantially different.  Now as to which one you actually want, this is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mistyped the second join. `Y7.ClassId = 8` shoud be `Y8.ClassId = 8`

```
SELECT 
    S.FirstName, S.LastName, S.StudentId, Y8.SectionId
FROM
    SR_Students AS S 
    INNER JOIN
    SR_Student_Classes AS Y7 ON 
        S.StudentId = Y7.StudentId
        AND S.IsActive = 1 AND S.Gender LIKE 'M%'
        AND Y7.TermId = 21 AND Y7.CampusId = 1 AND Y7.ClassId = 7 AND Y7.IsActive = 1
    INNER JOIN
    SR_Student_Classes AS Y8 ON 
        Y7.StudentId = Y8.StudentId
        AND Y8.TermId = 26 AND Y8.CampusId = 7 AND Y8.ClassId = 8 AND Y8.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for spotting my silly typo. Now both scripts are returning identical results. Really appreciate it